# How to allow a dynamic amount of users certain database permissions?

Tags: winforms, sql-server-2005, permissions

**I** have spent the past month or so developing an application using Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition and SQL Server 2005 which is a Windows Forms application that accesses a database allowing the user to perform CRUD tasks.

My *question/problem* now is how do I allow for a user on a different machine but same local network, to sign into the application (generic username/password) and start interacting with the database/application without any user permission errors.

I understand how to create users and grant certain permissions to said users but I am wondering of a way to do this without having to create new credentials/permissions for each unique person that uses this application.

Comment: sorry for the format I cannot get a grip on it.

Comment: What is your connection string? Do you have enabled the Integrated Security options? Is your server enabled to accept Windows Authentication?

Comment: Currently it is set up that the connection string is just using the SA for the database when logging in. Integrated security is false and Windows Authentication is not enabled. The user logs in just using a generic login name and the form verifies that the values match some hardcoded values in the project

Comment: Well, in this case I cannot see how you can really handle the situation without creating the users and the permissions for each specific user. In alternative you could add a single user for your app giving it full permissions, but you should handle the permissions on the client or build a security infrastructure yourself on the database. Not really an efficient way to use your time.

Comment: will the way it is currently set up using the 'sa' as the user in the connection string going to allow for any machine running this program to perform CRUD?

Comment: Yes, but I strongly suggest to create your own user. Do not mess with the sa user because you could create big problems (and not talking about the security)

Comment: ok thank you very much for your help!